# Building OpenCV for VS2008 in Windows. VC9 folder with libs not generated. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, git, opencv, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008

I followed the instructions for building OpenCV from source on the official website. The first issue was that it asked me to select the Sources folder which did not exist.

I selected the main parent folder and it went through. I am using the VS2008 Express compiler. Ideally this should generate vc9 folder under x86 with all the .lib files under it. Mine didn't.

All I got were the files below - 
    OpenCVModules.cmake
    OpenCVModules-debug.cmake
    OpenCVModules-release.cmake

Is there something I am missing? Did I clone the git properly? Should I get a sources folder when I clone the git?

PS: I used cmake-gui

Comment: after building the opencv libs, you should build the INSTALL project. this will copy anything required to whatever CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX is set to (build/install by default). and inside *that* should be x86/vc9/bin

Comment: Thank you! I'm using the Express edition however and I got several warnings - Solution folders are not supported. So projects like 3rdparty, c, gpu are all unavailable. Can I build those from inside the INSTALL.vcproj of each folder?

Comment: oh, right. set ENABLE_SOLUTION_FOLDERS to OFF in cmake-gui and build a new sln. there will be a couple more warts coming up ... ;)

Comment: Could you list the solutions to those warts as well? Thank you so much!

Comment: are you building 2.4.9 or 3.0 ? for the latter you'd need to get stdint.h and inttypes.h from somewhere, and put them into vc's include dir. did you get the src from github ? (also cleaning the  build folder, whenever something goes wrong seems to be a good idea)

Comment: ah, you already said github. so decide, if you want 2.4.9 (stable) or 3.0 (*very* unstable atm) and do a `git checkout 2.4` or a `git checkout master`. see, it all depends on a lot of details

Comment: oh dear god. Ok so what happens if i download that opencv-2-4-9.exe(not from git) and build that with ENABLE_SOLUTION_FOLDERS to OFF?
I built the git clone and it generated *300*.dll meaning it's the 3.0.0?

Comment: yes, that means 3.0. if it was from github, you don't need to download anything else (it's already on your box), all you need to do is change the git branch, clean up, and rerun cmake. still, ENABLE_SOLUTION_FOLDERS=OFF